# Is it trivial to train a NN to classify numbers as integers or non-integers?

Tags: neural-networks, classification

I understand that the data type of the inputs would have to be the same, but say that I have all of the numbers as floats with two decimals. Would a neural network be able to learn the classification:

```
X      y
100.00 1
100.09 0
100.70 0
78.00  1
78.17  0
...
```

Intuitively I think that it wouldn't be an easy task. Perhaps it is trivial but then I'm missing how it would work. Suprisingly some googling hasn't given any results (may be I'm not using the right terms...)

Edit: as per the comments below, in order to narrow down the question, let's suppose the Xs are stored as float variables defined in Python.

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what a "float with two decimals" actually is: would you be storing these as IEEE double-precision values? As text strings?  As integers equal to 100 times their values?  With some of these possibilities (especially the strings) the task ought to be much easier.

Comment: mm say that I store them as double-precision values. Would it make it difficult for the NN to differentiate?

Comment: Do you mean something like x=float(78.17) and y=float(100.00) using Python code?

Comment: I believe that storing them as double-precision floats might make the problem as difficult as possible ;-), unless you are passing the 64-bit sequences to the classifier (as 64 binary features).  It looks like "feature engineering" may be a key part of the problem and its solution.

Comment: Yes. See edit above.

Comment: I'm actually interested in convincing myself that it is not possible, since I want to train a GAN where the real objects are represented using integers (formatted to float) while the fake ones output by the generator have decimal values. Wondering whether the discriminator would catch that.

Comment: Maybe it *should* catch that.

Comment: It should be very easy for neural networks since it only needs to tell if the last two digits are zeros. Actually, you can just input them as strings.

Comment: Maybe try it out on a simple perceptron and see how well it does? One could easily simulate the data :)

Comment: Just spitballing, but I think this problem reduces to a whether an NN that can determine if $x \mod 1 > 0$ is true or false, so the answer turns on whether an NN can approximate the modulus function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't think this is possible in a vanilla (no feature engineering) approach.

Any neural network with continuous activations will produce a continuous function at the end.  Given a training set as you describe, it *is* reasonably likely that a network with enough neurons and, say, two layers will perfectly classify the training set: learn triples of first-layer neurons like $\operatorname{relu}(x-1.99)$, $\operatorname{relu}(x-2)$, and $\operatorname{relu}(x-2.01)$, then combine them (the first minus twice the second plus the third?) in a second-layer neuron to get a single spike around $x=2$.  This can happen around every integer in your training set, and nearby non-integers will regulate the width of the spikes.  (Although, as usual, in practice I can't currently get the neural net to learn its way into this structure.  I'll keep playing a little bit and update with a notebook if I'm successful.)

**But**, for any integer *not* in your training set, the network has no reason to deviate from this structure and give (significantly) positive values anywhere else.  And outside the training range, all bets are off for even the non-integers.  You would need some mechanism to encourage periodicity, but if you do that then the problem becomes (almost) trivial.

---

I got a bit of improvement in my attempts to train into the explicit network described above.  It's still rather dependent on the initial weights, and there are a couple of points it doesn't quite learn, but I lost interest in cleaning it up, so here it is:

[notebook link](https://github.com/bmreiniger/datascience.stackexchange/blob/master/CV512077-NN_integer_detection.ipynb)

[image: trained NN predictions]

The training data has each digit except 6 and then random non-integers in $(0, 10)$.  So there's nothing to enforce anything about negative numbers, and the integer 6 is unnoticed by the network.  (But the model has failed to understand 1, 2, 3, and seems to have superfluous kinks in the negative range.)